# How to change BarTextColor from the default white color in Xamarin Forms Android Project?

Tags: android, xamarin

Created a new Xamarin project and trying to change the color of the Navigation Bars background color(`BarBackgroundColor`) and text color(`BarTextColor`) inside it. Only the `BarBackgroundColor` seems to work and not the `BarTextColor`. Below is the resource in App.xaml.

```
        <Color x:Key="digiGreen">#ADC710</Color>
        <Color x:Key="whiteColor">#FFFFFF</Color>        

     <Style TargetType="NavigationPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
        <!-- navigation bar to have digiGreen color -->
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor"
                Value="{StaticResource digiGreen}"/>
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" 
                Value="{StaticResource whiteColor}"/>
    </Style>
```

Current Xamarin Version I am on is 4.12.xx and the Simulator is Android 9.0 - API 28

Comment: Xamarin forms version details? Thanks!

Comment: version 3.4.0.1008975

Comment: So it works with the Bar Color but not the Text Color?

Comment: exactly.. BarBackgroundColor works but not the BarTextColor.

Comment: Can I see how you have initialized your NavigationPage code?

Comment: public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            
        }

Comment: Are you using the `AppCompat` Backend?

Comment: "public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity"     Nope I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to change BarTextColor from the default white color in Xamarin
>   Forms Android Project?

I would recommend you using below codes to set the NavigationPage properties:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

    ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
    ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarTextColor = Color.OrangeRed;
}
```

Once you want to change the color in specific page, change it in the **Page Constructor**:

```
public Page1 ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;
    ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarTextColor = Color.Red;
}
```

**Note**: Don't change it in the Constructor of `MainPage` because you can't get `Application.Current.MainPage` at that time.

In xaml, I tested it in Android 9.0 and my xamarin.forms's version is 3.4.0.1008975. I use your code and it works on my side.

**Update:**

To change the TextColor of `toolbaritem` :
Go to `Android Project`-> `Resources` -> `values` -> `styles.xml` , add:

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ADC710</item>
```

To change the TextColor of `back arrow` :

Go to `Android Project`-> `Resources` -> `values` -> `styles.xml` , add:

```
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
```

And the style is:

```
  <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">#ADC710</item>
  </style>
```

`BarTextColor` will only affect the color of Navigationbar.title in Android. It's different due to different platform.

Refer:  [change-navigation-bar-back-button-color-in-xamarin-android](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103317/change-navigation-bar-back-button-color-in-xamarin-android)

Comment: @Yogi I just create an Android 9.0 emulator and it works for me. Can you try another emulator or a real device?

Comment: @Yogi BarTextColor works or BarBackgroundColor works?  In your comment, you said BarBackgroundColor works while here you say BarTextColor  works... Is your page background color white so that it looks the same as whiteColor of BarBackgroundColor  you set in your code.

Comment: sorry my mistake here, BarBackgroundColor works but not BarTextColor. BarTextColor always seems to be white in Android but it works (ie color is changed) in IoS

Comment: Even your code doesnt work in Android project, BarTextColor is always white

Comment: @Yogi Do you mean the color of title or other text? Color of ToolbarItems?

Comment: I mean both... The back '<' button and a toolbaritem on the right that is from my HomePage. This toolbaritem text and < back symbol is always white

Comment: No, BarTextColor  seems only changes the titleColor instead of the toolbaritem  in Android.

Comment: Ok. I am not having a title yet. But how do I change the back button color in Android. And why does this seems to work in IoS. Moreover I am testing on my Galaxy S9

Comment: Works perfect now but still confused why it works on IoS but not Android.

Answer (score 1):

For changing NavigationPage's BarTextColor and BarBackgroundColor you can:
In the app.xaml add then codel below:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```